# How to pass an array as a body from jQuery POST method to ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My Web API cannot recognize array parameters.
I have an array in front-end like this `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Now I want to pass it from the JSON body(not URL) to a Web API as follow:

**Back-end Code:**

```
// POST /api/result
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetResult([FromBody]int[] ids)
{
    //do something
}
```

**Front-end code(jQuery):**

```
var array = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
var ids = Json.stringify(array);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/result",
    data: ids,
    success: function (data, state) {
        alert("success!");
    },
    dataType: "json"
})
```

But what the api got is "[]" instead of ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `data: {ids:ids},` try passing with JSON format in your ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more property tu `$.ajax` function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    /*rest configuration*/
}
```

Then server side will be able to understand how to parse stringified content.

Some theory behind this issue: https://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/

Comment: This is what exactly I ignored! And the problem was perfectly solved! Thank you!